# AWS S3, CloudFront, web font CORS error

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I've just moved from my previous CDN to CloudFront for two of my websites. First one is working fine but I used the same snapshot in DigitalOcean to create the 2nd site and here I am getting

> Access to Font at
>   'http://CLOUDFRONT_HOSTNAME.cloudfront.net/wp-content/themes/Newspaper/images/icons/newspaper.woff?14'
>   from origin 'http://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

I've tried all possible solutions available in online like adding a header in nginx.

```
location ~* \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg|font.css)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Then updating privacy in S3

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Most of the solutions are this in various sites including other serverfault and stackoverflow solutions. I've also invalidated the font file in CloudFront, but no luck :(

Can someone please guide me what might be the issue? I've connected CloudFront via W3 Total Cache plugin in WP.

### **UPDATE**

**1. Whitelist Headers**

### [image: Whitelist Headers]

**2. Invalidated the files**

### [image: Invalidated the files]

3. Request and Response

[image: Request & Response]

*Thanks in Advance*

*Arif*

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you are sending `Authorization` header with your `GET` requests for the fonts?

If not, in your S3 CORS policy change

`<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>`

to

`<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>`.

This tiny miss had bugged me for a month.

Comment: Worst kind of bug.

Comment: Yes it is . It wasted so much of my time back then.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for this today and wasn't able to find any working answer for my scenario.

I am using wordpress and using s3 bucket based origin push cdn with amazon cloudfront. However the font files were giving the error for CORS.

The error said:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://–domain–.cloudfront.net/wp-content/themes/Extra/fonts/ET-Extra.ttf. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control_Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

The Solution was to set the CORS permissions from s3 bucket. But not the default ones. I changed them to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>http://www.domain-here.com</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedOrigin>https://www.domain-here.com</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedOrigin>http://domain-here.com</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedOrigin>https://domain-here.com</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Make sure to change the domain-here to your own domain name.

Also, don't forget to clear your cache / invalidate the file which was giving issue, if needed.

You can see this tutorial for guidance too: https://nabtron.com/fix-access-control-allow-origin-missing/

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In AWS console - CloudFront - Distribution edit behavior, in fordward header set Whitelist and add Origin from the whitelist headers.

Comment: Well, already tried this also.. added *Origin*  and *Access-Control-Allow-Origin*, no change.

Comment: have you invalidated cache?

Comment: Invalidated */wp-content/themes/Newspaper/images/icons/newspaper.woff*.. not sure if it will work as still the same result.

Comment: or do it take long time to clear the cache from CloudFront even after invalidate?

Comment: Imgur: http://imgur.com/NkCLQho

Comment: @ArifulHaque, configure `Access-Control-Request-Headers` and `Access-Control-Request-Method`, in addition to `Origin` as whitelisted in the Cache Behavior config in CloudFront. Next, invalidations are against the *path*, so don't include the query string -- `?` or anything after it -- in the invalidation request.  Once the invalidation request shows complete, it is complete.  Then, look at the request and response headers associated with the next failed request.  Edit them into the original question if their meaning is unclear.  This is easy to troubleshoot if you look in the right place.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for explain.. I've updated the question with all images. Can you please see? It seems like the request is not going properly.

Answer (score 0):

@Ariful Haque please add the below code to your .htaccess file. it will help you out.

```
# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```